# Open all PDFs in a folder

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd, directory, directory-structure

I want to open multiple PDFs in a folder with the program "Drawboard PDF".
The PDFs are in subfolders, so just Ctrl+A and then Enter won't suffice.
Is there a way to do it?

I thought, perhaps it is doable via a batch file or some cmd commands, unfotunately I have little knowledge in these topics.

If you have an idea, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions. Question probably belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan here from Drawboard. If Drawboard PDF is set as your default PDF application, you can select multiple PDFs in your file browser and then right-click: Open. They will all open in Drawboard PDF.

Comment: The problem is that these files are nested in subfolders of a folder. I can't simply select them all at once.

Comment: Gotcha. I checked with one of the engineering team and unfortunately the app doesn't currently cater to opening multiple files via command line.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying. Perhaps opening all PDFs in a folder could be a useful feature, I'd be willing to pay for that ;)

Comment: I'll let the team know!